# Opsworks - Chef: Rake in opsworks chef hook running sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I'm using a before_restart.rb hook in opsworks and I have a problem when it run "rake i18n:js:export". I don't know why is running sidekiq with this rake. it fails only in setup stage of opsworks. When I deploy it the error disappears.

```
[2015-01-09T18:52:17+00:00] INFO: deploy[/srv/www/XXX] queueing checkdeploy hook /srv/www/XXX/releases/20150109185157/deploy/before_restart.rb
[2015-01-09T18:52:17+00:00] INFO: Processing execute[rake i18n:js:export] action run (/srv/www/XXXX/releases/20150109185157/deploy/before_restart.rb line 3)


Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[rake i18n:js:export]'


Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed

Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of bundle exec rake i18n:js:export ----
STDOUT: 2015-01-09T18:52:30Z 1808 TID-92c6g INFO: Sidekiq client with redis options {}
STDERR: /home/deploy/.bundler/XXXX/ruby/2.1.0/gems/redis-3.1.0/lib/redis/client.rb:309:in `rescue in establish_connection': Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)
```

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379 (ECONNREFUSED) (Redis::CannotConnectError)... at that point there is no Redis service running at port 6379 obviously.

Comment: yes I know that, but I don't know why is running sidekiq in a rake i18n task and why is asking for a redis server locally if I have the redis server in a remote server (configured in initializers/sidekiq.rb).

Answer (score 0):

Sidekiq client (NOT sidekiq server) is running because it is defined in an initializer. When rake runs, it loads the entire rails app environment. So either allow for an environment variable to disable sidekiq client in `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` or make sure redis-server is properly configured on the instance you're running this on.

```
unless ENV['DISABLE_SIDEKIQ']
  # Sidekiq.configure...
end

DISABLE_SIDEKIQ=true bundle exec rake do:stuff
```